# Rendering JSONP in Django Views

Tags: python, json, django, jsonp

I understand how to render JSON view in Django, but I don't understand the python code required to render JSONP. I did find solution but I don't understand it.

```
def jsonp_api(request)
    ...
    if 'callback' in request.REQUEST:
        data = '%s(%s);' % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
    ...
```

What does the `request.REQUEST` do? And what exactly happens here:

```
'%s(%s);' % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)
```

Answer (score 2):

1.`request.REQUEST` is a combine of `POST` and `GET`, which as far as I understand means 'what does the client want?'. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) for more info.

2.`%s(%s); % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)` equals `the_callback_function(data);` which means the call of the callback function with the `data` as the parameter. `%` is a python string format tool, you can check [this](http://importflying.com/2011/conversational-programming-how-to-use-the-percent-sign-operator-in-python/) for more info.